# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'D:\JBoss\EAP-7.0.0\bin\content\eArsiv.war\WEB-INF\lib\lept4j-1.2.3.jar\win32-x86-64' does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, tess4j

I was developing an application with Spring Boot and using tess4j for OCR process.
It was jar packaging and working well.

I just changed packaging to war and deployed to jBoss EAP7.Now i am getting "Source 'D:\JBoss\EAP-7.0.0\bin\content\eArsiv.war\WEB-INF\lib\lept4j-1.2.3.jar\win32-x86-64' does not exist" error and TessAPI cant be initialized.

Normally there is no folder as content under bin folder but anyway i have created subfolders under bin folder but still no chance.

How can i handle this case?

Many thanks in advance!
Cheers,
Murat

Comment: I found a solution for Tomcat in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012873/tess4j-error-after-distributing-as-war-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initializ but it doesnt work for jBoss

Comment: You may want to try tess4j-3.4.0, which adds support for jboss-vfs protocol, which may help.

Comment: Thanks anyway man, we have decided to use Tomcat (: